# Statistics: Choose the best estimator.

Tags: statistics

Alright, there is two people, Paul and Joe that goes fishing salomon with a unknown expected value $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma $

Paul fishes five salmons with avg. weight $X$ and Joe fishes three salmons with avg. weight $Y$. which of the following two estimators is the best?

$\mu_1 = (X+Y)/2$,  $\mu_2 = (5X+3Y)/8$

according to the solution sheet the variance is supposed to be

$\operatorname{Var}(\mu_1) = (8/60) \sigma^2$
and
$\operatorname{Var}(\mu_2) = (8/64)\sigma^2$

why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $P=P_{1}+P_{2}+P_{3}+P_{4}+P_{5}$ and $J=J_{1}+J_{2}+J_{3}$ where the $P_{i}$ denotes the weight of the $i$-th fish caught by Paul and  $J_{i}$ denotes the weight of the $i$-th fish caught by Joe. You allready mention the distribution of these weights and secondly the weights are independent. Now $X=P/5$ and $Y$=$J/3$. What can you say about the distribution of $(X+Y)/2$ and $(5X+3Y)/8=(P+J)/8$?

Answer (score 0):

Since Paul and Joe are sampling from the same distribution, there's no reason not to combine their catches to get one sample of size $8$.  The total catch is
$5 X + 3 Y$, and as it is the sum of $8$ independent random variables each with variance $\sigma^2$, its variance is $8 \sigma^2$.  Then $\mu_2 = (5X + 3Y)/8$ has variance $8 \sigma^2/8^2 = (8/64) \sigma^2$.

Comment: Thanks! but how can var($\mu_1$) be 8/60?